# Clear data automatically for the app on Update

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, google-play-services

I have created an android app using Ionic 1 and Angular Js 1 . When I set any update for the app on play store. After the update , App starts working offline . It gives many errors . But when I clear data for the same, it starts working fine and as expected . This can only be solved by clear data and not by uninstalling. This problem never comes in Locally created and installed app . 
Is there a function which needs to be called to force the clear data every time, we update the app? 
Thank You.

Comment: Please add some codes. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO there is some data that messes up your app behaviour on update.
If the only acceptable solution for you is clearing the data, then you can go for something like `$localStorage.$reset()`.

As in, check for `device ready`, and then setup a local variable (for version check like `currentVersion`) to store the version of installed app and compare with previous. As in, if app's version (which you can hardcode or fetch from config) is not same as the one stored in local storage, then you clear all the data and store the new `currentVersion` for future checks during update.

Comment: Thanks. I hardcoded and called a function to force clear data after app version change and it works fine now.